# If-Statement with Paperclip | Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, if-statement, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have to create 300px widht thumbnails **if the file is a picture** ('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif') and **no** thumbnails if the file has an other extension. I'm using Paperclip for file-upload (it's working great without the conditions...).

:file is the uploaded file and if it is an image, Paperclip should create a *medium* version of it.

```
class Paperplanes < ActiveRecord::Base
   if validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
      has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :medium => "x300>" }
   else
      has_attached_file :file
   end
end
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Hope you guys can find a solution. THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it isn't an image, thumbnail creation should fail. If `whiny` isn't true, that should be the end of it. (Mostly; you'd need to check for thumbnail presence then, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801482/rails-paperclip-attachments-knowing-if-theres-a-image-thumbnail).)

If you want to completely control the process, you could either open up the default [`Thumbnail` processor](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb) to add/change its normal options/handling, or use it as a guide to create your own processor (see the "Post Processing" section on [Paperclip's github page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)).

You could also play some games with a [`lambda` style](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation), perhaps creating a default "non-image" thumbnail for non-image files.